# Creating Activity | Android Studio ? [Some concerns]

Tags: android, android-studio

Till Eclipse, creating a second activity and class had a brevity . However, with the new official Android studio , I feel more of an abstraction . Earlier, while creating an activity it specified many things, nevertheless asked the layout of an XML file. And here are my doubts:

1) Is there an option to create Java file in Android Studio just like we use to do with Eclipse ?

2) Which is the best way to create an activity in Android Studio with our specified layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can go into the project directory and right click the folder where you want the activity to be (typically in src/java/com.xxx.xxx/) and select New -> JavaClass and create YourActivity and make sure that YourActivity extends Activity. Be sure to add the activity to your manifest!

2) There is no best way as it is a matter of preference. Personally I do what I said in step 1 and create the xml layout file myself in the res folder. I find that Android Studios auto activity creation to be a bit annoying as they add menu xml files that I do not need.

Comment: okay! that'll do! But again , how to specify the layout of xml while it's created ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your question is, but I'll try to infer. If you mean where in the activity do you specify what layout to use, then you do so in the Activity's onCreate method. In that method call setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT);